# how to call javascript/jQuery when javascript is disabled in mozilla/ie?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to call javascript/jQuery when javascript is disabled in mozilla/ie ?

Comment: How to see if I have no eyes?

Answer (score 6):

If javascript is disabled you cannot use it. It's as simple as that. You can use the [`<noscript>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp) tag to show some contents to the user if javascript is disabled inciting him to enable it because your site relies on javascript.

Comment: ok,but is it any solution for that??

Comment: @Hitesh No. The point of disabling Javascript is that no Javascript can run.

Answer (score 2):

If the user disabled Javascript, then it is disabled.  Your only option is to display a message on the page saying, "Please enable Javascript."

Comment: thats' i am talking. that is any futher soluction to call javascript function?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, it is a *user* preference. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build) so this isn't a problem.